# Reversing of string

Tags: java, reverse

I have a string as Apple->Ball->Cat->Dog and want to reverse it as Dog->Cat->Ball->Apple. It can be done by splitting the string at every '->' and then adding each element is an array and then reverse the array and then add the arrows. But is there any faster way to do so? What would be the quickest possible way of reversing it using java?

Comment: Are all of the entries a single character?

Comment: No entries are names not a single character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use tokenization. You may try `StringBuffer` reverse method:

```
String input = "A->B->C->D";
input = input.replace("->", "-");
input = new StringBuffer(input).reverse().toString();
input = input.replace("-", "->");
System.out.println(input);
```

This will hold the -> in the right order:

```
input: "A->B->C->D"
output: "D->C->B->A"
```

Good Luck;

**[EDIT]:**

Ok, at first you didn't mention that the your String may contains other than single characters. So the above answer cannot maintain your needs. But if you have unique names in your string you may use this way by substituting every name with a single character and it works. But I'm not sure it would be better than your own solution(Tokenize to an array and reverse the array).

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that its not of a single character. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

For better performance use this. I am assuming that your `A,B,C,D` are literally characters then you can take advantage of the position in string. Just convert your string into StringBuilder and do the following.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("A->B->C->D");
int len = sb.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i+=3) {
  int j = len - (i + 1);
  char temp = sb.charAt(i);
  sb.setCharAt(i, sb.charAt(j));
  sb.setCharAt(j, temp);
}
System.out.print(sb.toString());
```

Comment: those are not single characters. Those are name of various cities

Answer (score -1):

If it is only one character after each arrow, it might be faster to use `replaceAll("->", "")` so that you get rid of all the arrows, reverse the String you get (if you didn't remove the `->` you'd obviously reverse the arrows aswell), and then add your arrows after each character. That being said it probably doesn't change much on the scope of performance, and it doesn't work with strings longer than 1 character, so I would just stick to your original plan.